# Orientation of manifold in topological sense

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

What do we mean by orientability of a topological manifold? How do we orient two dimensional Euclidean space and why is Moebius band non-orientable? And it would be a great favour to me if you can tell me a good book that explains this idea. I read "Algebraic topology: An Introduction" by W. S. Massey but have a confusion.